# validity of adiabatic equation

Tags: thermodynamics

Is $p\cdot V^γ= \mathrm{const.}$ valid for only adiabatic reversible process and not for adiabatic irreversible process if not why?
Today I was doing an objective question as mentioned above and chose option "any adiabatic process" but the ans was "only reversible adiabatic process" but i couldn't understand why. All i know is that path followed by both process will be different but how will it affect the adiabatic equation i.e $p\cdot V^γ= \mathrm{const}$.

Answer (score 2):

An [adiabatic and reversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process) process (i.e. isentropic) for ideal gases can be described as follows<sup>1</sup>:

$p \cdot V^\gamma = \mathrm{const.}$

Here $\gamma$ is the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio). Other processes can be described by changing the exponent. The equation for a [polytropic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process) is:

$p \cdot V^n= \mathrm{const.}$

For $n=1$ this equation describes a [isothermal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_process) process and for values greater $\gamma$ this equation can be used to describe irreversible processes.

---

[1]: [Wikipedia: Isentropic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isentropic_process#Table_of_isentropic_relations_for_an_ideal_gas)